# Additional Configuration to disable anonymous session cookies?

Tags: sessions, cookies, 6

I am running a clean install of Pressflow 6.28. I have set the following configurations:

Cache Mode: Normal;
Min Cache Lifetime: 5 minutes;
Page Cache Max Age: 1 day;

I have installed no contributed modules and have disabled all optional modules that ship with Pressflow.

I am seeing inconsistent behavior with setting session cookies with anonymous users. Sometimes a session is not set, but most of the time it is. When I login and logout, session remains set. If session is not being set and I run 'drush cc all' it begins to be set. I am wondering if there is perhaps some additional configuration I may be missing.

Comment: Pressflow won't disallow anonymous sessions altogether because sometimes they are needed (eg. for shopping cart). Anonymous visitors who don't login should not get session cookies, that's the only difference from standard Drupal in this respect IIRC. So I think what you are seeing is expected behaviour. Shouldn't be a problem anyway for most sites.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the $cookie_domain is set properly in settings.php, often if it's not set to the correct domain, particularly in proxy situations, you'll see inconsistent login behaviour.